# Ubuntu Shell Scripting Issue

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting

Hello I am trying to make a program in Ubuntu shell and the program crashes after I input the variables. The code is as follows: http://pastebin.com/Chu4DPgF

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter assignment mark:"
read assign

echo -n "Enter Test 1 mark:"
read test1

echo -n "Enter Test 2 mark:"
read test2

echo -n "Enter Final Exam mark:"
read final

total=$(($assign + $test1 + $test2 + $final))

if [[ $total -ge 90  &&  $total -le 100 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is A+"

elif [[ $total -ge 85  &&  $total -le 89 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is A"

elif [[ $total -ge 80  &&  $total -le 84 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is A-";

elif [[ $total -ge 77  &&  $total -le 79 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is B+"

elif [[ $total -ge 73  &&  $total -le 76 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is B"

elif [[ $total -ge 70  &&  $total -le 72 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is B-"

elif [[ $total -ge 67  &&  $total -le 69 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is C+"

elif [[ $total -ge 63  &&  $total -le 66 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is C"

elif [[ $total -ge 60  &&  $total -le 62 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is C-"

elif [[ $total -ge 57  &&  $total -le 59 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is D+"

elif [[ $total -ge 53  &&  $total -le 56 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is D"

elif [[ $total -ge 50  &&  $total -le 52 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is D-"

elif [[ $total -ge 0  &&  $total -le 49 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is F"

else
echo "?"
fi
```

I have no idea what is wrong with the code. I'm sure there is a fundamental problem with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include your code in the question. (BTW, I grabbed a copy of your script, and it worked fine for me.)

Comment: What do you input and what's the error message?

Comment: i inputted 10 for all the grades and i crash right after i input the 4th

Answer (score -1):

change line 15 to

((total = assign + test1 + test2 + final ))

and all the following lines of this format to:

```
if [[ $total -ge 90  &&  $total -le 100 ]]; then
echo "Your grade is A+"
```

to

```
if [ $total -ge 90 ] && [ $total -le 100 ]; then
  echo "Your grade is A+"
```

and it should work.
Be exact with the white-spaces

Comment: You cannot use `&&` in the middle of the `test` command line.

Comment: true, my fault. change [ $total -ge 90  &&  $total -le 100 ]
to
[ $total -ge 90 ] && [ $total -le 100 ]; then